# Make faulty PL/pgSQL functions fail during creation (not on first call)

Tags: postgresql, compiler-errors, plpgsql

At the `psql` prompt (or in a script file), I am doing a (this is just for illustration purposes):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FOO() RETURNS VOID AS 'BEGIN SELECT 1 FROM doesntexist; END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... where the table `doesntexist` doesn't exist. The function is created **without** any complaints and only fails upon calling it:

```
test=> select foo() ;
ERROR:  relation "doesntexist" does not exist
...
```

How can I change that behavior so that I can be confident that once my script is executed there are no errors of that type lurking?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to perform this kind of validation when you create a function. IMHO if you want to be sure test your code. There is pgtap (https://github.com/theory/pgtap/), Python with psycopg and unittest works great too.

Comment: Even if the table exists, there's no guarantee that the calling role has permission to query it. Different error, but an error nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Not with current PL/pgSQL. It does not check identifiers at compile time.

Call the function once to check. Do it in a transaction and roll back to avoid side effects:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT foo();
ROLLBACK;
```

There have been attempts to provide a stricter variant, mostly by Pavel Stehule, but I don't know how mature they are.

- [PLPSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM)  ([announced May 2011](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1305291347.14548.13.camel@jara.office.nic.cz))
- [plpgsql lint](http://okbob.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/plpgsql-lint.html)
- [**plpgsql_check**](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check) ([anounced Dec. 2013](http://okbob.blogspot.co.at/2013/12/new-postgresql-extension-plpgsqlcheck.html))

Comment: plpgsql_lint is good for production usage, and it used in production (in some critical applications) and I have a good references. There are a few limits - it cannot to check a references to temporary tables and it has a few limits when dynamic SQL is used (but these limits are natural - is not possible to fully complete static analyse in possible dynamic environment)